# How to view the exact raw HTTP request on Postman?

Tags: http, http-request

When I'm sending a request, the raw log looks something like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.36.3
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3d4eba45-388c-462c-a174-e003d2a36456
Host: google.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
 
----------------------------postman
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"
tst 123
```

[image: Request Settings]

Is that the real request being sent via HTTP, or is this a formatted decoded request?

There is a lot of white spaces and blank lines. How are request's ending lines and white spaces sent? Are they sent with /r/n for Windows as usual? Is there a way to inspect that?

**EDIT:**

I intercepted the call via WireShark:

[image]

The line endings are encoded as \r\n and the white spaces are not encoded at all. How is it possible?

Hex dump:

0000   50 4f 53 54 20 2f 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d
0010   0a 55 73 65 72 2d 41 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 50 6f 73
0020   74 6d 61 6e 52 75 6e 74 69 6d 65 2f 37 2e 33 36
0030   2e 33 0d 0a 41 63 63 65 70 74 3a 20 2a 2f 2a 0d
0040   0a 50 6f 73 74 6d 61 6e 2d 54 6f 6b 65 6e 3a 20
0050   31 65 36 35 62 39 33 31 2d 39 61 31 66 2d 34 39
0060   32 37 2d 38 36 62 64 2d 31 39 30 66 63 39 65 65
0070   66 36 66 63 0d 0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 67 6f 6f 67
0080   6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d 0d 0a 41 63 63 65 70 74 2d 45
0090   6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3a 20 67 7a 69 70 2c 20 64
00a0   65 66 6c 61 74 65 2c 20 62 72 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 6e
00b0   65 63 74 69 6f 6e 3a 20 6b 65 65 70 2d 61 6c 69
00c0   76 65 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 65
00d0   3a 20 6d 75 6c 74 69 70 61 72 74 2f 66 6f 72 6d
00e0   2d 64 61 74 61 3b 20 62 6f 75 6e 64 61 72 79 3d
00f0   2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d
0100   2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 31 30 34 30 39 33
0110   36 35 38 32 32 34 30 38 38 32 35 36 36 34 32 37
0120   34 35 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 4c 65 6e 67
0130   74 68 3a 20 31 36 37 0d 0a 0d 0a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the actual, real request that is being transmitted.
The HTTP protocol is a text-based protocol and it is not particularly dense.

If you want to go deeper, you can use a tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the low-level network interaction and see exactly what bytes are being sent on the various protocols (IP, TCP, HTTP).

Comment: Aha, I thought it's going to at least do a \r\n instead of those blank lines?

Comment: @DevelBase2, `\r\n` marks the end of a line. Starting at the beginning of a new line is how that character sequence is printed.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not in the raw log. The \r\n is missing. In the actual request, does it send new lines as blank lines, or does it send as \r\n? I am downloading Wireshark now

Comment: @DevelBase2 The character sequence `\r\n` doesn't mean new line. Within a string literal in many programming languages, it is defined to be translated into new line character(s), but HTTP is a protocol, not a programming language

Comment: It almost sounds like @DevelBase2 is debugging line ending issues in HTTP requests.

Comment: @DevelBase2, show us a hex byte dump from `tcpdump -x` or from WireShark.

Comment: I intercepted the call via WireShark and found out some exciting news! Edited my original post. @J_H I copied the Hex Dump from WireShark and added it.

Comment: The CRLF CRLF looks normal to me. >>> from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
>>> 
>>> def squish(s):
...   return ''.join(s.split()).encode()
... 
>>> 
>>> unhexlify(squish('2d 64 61 74 61 3b 20 62 6f 75 6e 64 61 72 79 3d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 31 30 34 30 39 33 36 35 38 32 32 34 30 38 38 32 35 36 36 34 32 37 34 35 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 4c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20 31 36 37 0d 0a 0d 0a'))
b'-data; boundary=--------------------------104093658224088256642745\r\nContent-Length: 167\r\n\r\n'